# au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received:

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, pact

This test case is for mocking the health check contract.
TestClass

```
@Pact(consumer = "Consumer")
public RequestResponsePact getHealthCheck(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    headers.put("callchainid", "a4275861-f60a-44ab-85a6-c0c2c9df5e27");

    return builder
            .given("get health check")
            .uponReceiving("get health data")
            .path("/health")
            .method("GET")
            .headers(headers )
            .willRespondWith()
            .status(200)
            .body("{\"status\":\"UP\",\"components\":{\"db\":{\"status\":\"UP\",\"details\":{\"database\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"validationQuery\":\"isValid()\"}}}}")
            .toPact();
}

@Test
@PactTestFor(pactMethod = "getHealthCheck")
void getHealthData(MockServer mockServer) {

    WebClient webClient=WebClient.builder().baseUrl(mockServer.getUrl()).build();
    final String callChainId="a4275861-f60a-44ab-85a6-c0c2c9df5e27";
    ThreadContext.put(CallChainIdService.HEADER_NAME, callChainId);
    AsyncClient asyncClient=new AsyncClient(webClient);
    Mono<ClientResponse> responseMono=asyncClient.getHealthCheck();
    System.out.println(responseMono);


}
```

Here the webclient end point code which i am trying to hit,
AsyncClient Class
private final WebClient CLIENT;

```
@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> getHealthCheck() {
  return get(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, "/health");
}

private Mono<ClientResponse> get(MediaType contentType, String uri, Object... params) {
return CLIENT
  .mutate()
  .defaultHeader(CallChainIdService.HEADER_NAME, ThreadContext.get(CallChainIdService.HEADER_NAME))
  .build()
  .get()
  .uri(uri, params)
  .accept(contentType)
  .exchange();
```

}

When i run the test , i got PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received.

```
 au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received:
method: GET
path: /health
query: {}
headers: {callchainid=[a4275861-f60a-44ab-85a6-c0c2c9df5e27], Content-Type=[text/plain]}
matchers: MatchingRules(rules={})
generators: Generators(categories={})
body: MISSING
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. Appreciate your inputs and help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `content-type` as the expected header you send in the GET call, but in fact you send only an `accept` header (both with the media type `text/plain`).

I think your test should be updated to use `accept`.